# Sharepoint checkin/checkout

Tags: sharepoint, document

We have a sharepoint based application that uses a custom database for storing metadata/files (which could also be on a file share)

My question is how can the standard file checkin/check out option in document library  be customized?

The javascript file ows.js in the layouts folder contains the functions that provide checkin/check out/ open file functionality. Behind the scenes it relies on a combination of HTTP Post/GET methods + SOAP + an activeX control to achieve the desired functionality.

Customizing these javascript function seems tedious/error prone.

Note that we have a web service that exposes endpoints, for retrieving necessary file information/data from the backend. The difficulty is in integrating it with the sharepoint js functions, due to lack of proper documentation. (Also the js functions might change over different versions of sharepoint)

Also is it possible to create files/open files etc from the cache area on the client machine from server side code?

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of customization you wish to achieve? Also, creating/opening files on the client is not possible from purely server-side code (thankfully).

Comment: Eventually I ended up using the Sharepoint event receivers + custom content type, since it was good enough for what we needed. Thanks for the replies Paul and JD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this answers your question, but one technique for customizing checkin/checkout is through SharePoint Event Receivers.

[Here is an](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736146.aspx) introduction to buolding Event Receivers with SharePoint.